# Using sessions in ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6)

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble getting sessions to work in my MVC 6 project.

I read a [great article about this](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/270/sessions-in-asp-net-5) , but I cant get `app.UseInMemorySession();` to work in my `Startup.cs` as described.

I added `"Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta6"`to the dependencies part of my `project.json` and modified my `Startup.cs` as follows:

My Configuration part looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add MVC services to the services container.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddSession();
    services.AddCaching();
}
```

My Configure part looks like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Information;
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

        // Add the following to the request pipeline only in development environment.
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // Add Error handling middleware which catches all application specific errors and
            // send the request to the following path or controller action.
            app.UseErrorHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        // Add static files to the request pipeline.
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        // Configure sessions:
        //app.UseInMemorySession();

        // Add MVC to the request pipeline.
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Note that `app.UseInMemorySession();` is commented out, since if I enable it, I get the following error:

```
'IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseInMemorySession' and no extension method 'UseInMemorySession' accepting a first argument of type 'IApplicationBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If I try to run the application without `app.UseInMemorySession();` I get the following error when using sessions:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.AspNet.Http.dll but was not handled in user code
```

[image: InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code]

Any advice on how to solve this problem is appreciated :-)

Comment: Have you tried checking out [the source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Session) and directly referencing that? The method you're trying to use is at `Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.SessionMiddlewareExtensions`. Did you add a using statement for `Microsoft.AspNet.Builder`? (it's probably there by default, but might as well confirm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use:

```
app.UseSession();
```

It lives in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Builder` namespace, so you should not need the `Session` namespace.

See: https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/1.0.0-beta6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Session/SessionMiddlewareExtensions.cs

Comment: Correct you are - I was 56 seconds too late in posting a similar answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems I needed two changes.

First I needed to add `using Microsoft.AspNet.Session;`, and I had to change:
`app.UseInMemorySession();`
to
`app.UseSession();`
in the Configure part of `Startup.cs`.

At least when I do this, it starts working without throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a note for anyone trying to use rc2, you get the following exception.

> ILoggerFactory' does not contain a definition for 'MinimumLevel' and no extension method 'MinimumLevel' accepting a first argument of type 'ILoggerFactory' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The MinimumLevel has been removed as per the following breaking change:
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/122

```
 loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Information;
```

That line just needs removing from your code (and OP's code) for rc2+.